# Range of a function of two variables given by two sentences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, graphing-functions

I was given the following function:
$$f(x, y) := \begin{cases}
             2 - \frac{1}{x^2\,+\,y^2}  & \text{if } 0<x^2 + y^2 \leqslant 1 \\
             \sqrt{x^2 + y^2-1}  & \text{if } 1 < x^2 + y^2
       \end{cases} \quad$$
How can I find it's range? 
I'm conviced it is the interval $(0, 1]$, by simple calculation. 
Is it right? It's simple, but I'm a little concerned about the disjoint intervals of the ranges of the piecewise functions.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

I'm not sure why you consider the range is $(0,1]$. Instead, for the first part, consider what happens to $f(x,y) = 2 - \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$ as $x^2 + y^2 \to 0^{+}$. For the second part, consider what happens to $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - 1}$ as $x^2 + y^2 \to \infty$.

Comment: So the range will be the entire real line, but why can one proceed like this, by analysing the limits? My approach was something like $2 - \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \leqslant 1$, for the first sentence (similarly for the second), what gives the interval $(0, 1]$.

Comment: @BrazilianAeronautics Yes, the range is the entire real line. As for your approach, note the range is the *union* of the ranges for each part, not the *intersection*. This is because there's no overlap between the domains for each part, i.e., $x^2 + y^2$ *must* belong to either the first part or the second part of the definition. As such, the set of *all* possible results would be what you get from the first part's results along with those of the second part. In particular, this means the range would be $(-\infty,1]\cup (0,\infty) = (-\infty,\infty)$.